# How to write/ read/ modify array to XML file?

Tags: c#, arrays, xml

I have an array which its structure is:

```
<data>
<id></id>
<list></list>
</data>
```

And I want to write an array to list node

```
<data>
<id></id>
<list>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</list>
</data>
```

Then, delete an element in that array:

```
<data>
<id></id>
<list>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>3</item>
    <item>4</item>
</list>
</data>
```

Next, modify that array:

```
<data>
<id></id>
<list>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</list>
</data>
```

How to write / read/ modify an array which inside the xml array?

Any ideas?

Comment: XElement, XDocument are few examples which you can read

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing XML document using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407001/editing-xml-document-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @Damith I read it as a text file. Split it by <list> first, then remove </list>. Second, get all data in <item> node by using split and convert it  to list.

Comment: @cansik What I have to do with your suggested answer? `var page = xdoc.Descendants("data");  if (page != null)
{
    page.Element("list")
        .Add(new XElement("item", 4
                 ));

    xdoc.Save("Test.xml");
}`

Comment: @MRfuxkYou It's about editing an xml file with C#. You did not ask a concrete question, so learn first to work with xml files and then ask a specific question if you have one.

Answer (score 2):

To read:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var listPath = from elements in doc.Elements("data").Elements("list") select elements;

foreach (var docItem in listPath)
{
 var itemVar= Convert.ToInt32(doc .Element("item").Value);               
}
```

To write:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var list = doc.Root.Element("list");
list.Add(new XElement("item", value));
```

To edit:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("data.xml");
var list = doc.Root.Element("list");
list.Element("item").Value = newValue;
```

any powerful and faster solution?

Comment: Hey, does anyone know how to delete all item in list?